# Ganache Processing becomes very slow (with Automining Option) after consecutive thousands transactions

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs, ganache

I am trying to deploy thousands of contracts on Ganache GUI. At first, it process all transactions very fast (deploy contracts and transactions for calling setters functions) . After some transactions, may 500/1000 or more, it become so slow and **process a single transaction in 5-8 seconds or sometime even more** . **Is it normal ? It is because of calculating difficulty level , automatically ?....**

Answer (score 2):

Try to work with [ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) instead of [ganache-gui](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache).

We faced similar issues with our integration tests - lots of transactions are very slow with the Ganache GUI (especially under Windows the UI has update problems).

The command line interface ganache-cli is much more stable and runs in terminal as well as in docker container. From the functional point of view, you have everything that you need in ganache-cli.

Ganache GUI is nice for demonstrations to management & customers or training sessions. During development and for test purposes, it's better to use the ganache-cli.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try and update you...

Comment: yes, now i have also tried Ganache CLI v6.7.0 (ganache-core: 2.8.0), and the same problem.. you can see my same kind of question there ... https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78728/ganache-become-disconnected-after-some-hours?noredirect=1#comment96474_78728

Answer (score 0):

Ganache is not well suited for complex deployments or resource intensive contracts. Although 1000 txs doesn't seems to much, perhaps it is constrained by your VM resources like memory or CPU.

As alternative I'll suggest to try geth or parity in development chain mode. They should work quite similar to ganache in automine mode.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try your suggestion, HOWEVER, if i still want to use Ganache.. then I am facing unresponsiveness of Ganache, if i left my laptop unattended. NOTED that i have already disable power option to never for sleeping

Comment: @ismael does geth or parity in development chain mode support methods like `hardhat_setSorageAt`?

Comment: @HristoTodorov It will be better if you create a new question for that issue. I haven't used geth recently, so I can't help you there.