# Ganache become disconnected after some hours

Tags: ganache

I am running my program to deploy thousand of contracts and millions of transaction to interact with them, which definitely need a lot of hours. But, when i let my program running during night (without using my laptop at all), then **Ganache GUI** become **disconnected after some hours, which cause my program to stop.** and my program shows this error `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""`

It should be noted that i turned off all option of auto sleep and choose Never/Do nothing options. Why Ganache become unresponsive  after some hours ? Is there any way to keep Ganache running all the time ?

**UDDATE:** 
my code is here

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:8545");
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const account1 = "0x2cAe18ac37d85CccdE2e...." // Ganache GUI
const privateKey1 ="0x19c30ab1a928ab11f18..........." // Ganache GUI

//////////////////// Final Deploy //////////////////////////////
async function finalDeploy(r){

    const options = {
      data: '0x' + myBin[0]+constructorParams[r],
      gas: 5000000,
  };
  const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey1);
  const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
  console.log("Contract: is deployed at  " +receipt.contractAddress);
  var address = receipt.contractAddress;
  return address;
  // contractAddressess.push(receipt.contractAddress)


}
//////////////////// Final Setter //////////////////////////////
async function finalSettersFunctions(address, r, j){
  var myFunc; 
      myContAddr = address;

          myFunc = finalSetters[r][j];

            try {
              await web3.eth.sendTransaction(
                // web3.eth.sendTransaction(
                {from:account1,
                // nonce: myNonce,
                to:myContAddr,
                data: myFunc
                    }, function(err, receipt) {
                      console.log("Normal Setters: ",receipt)
                    //   myNonce++;
                    //   console.log("Current nonce Normal is : ", myNonce)
                    });
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(" Normal Setters: ERROR !", error); 
            //   myNonce--;
            }
}

//////////// Getting Status ////////////////////////
async function finalGetStatus(statusArr, address) {
  var myFunc; 
  var myFuncParams; 
  var res;
  var myContractAbiDefenition = myAbi[0]

    var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(myContractAbiDefenition, address);
    for(j=0; j<selectorObjects.length; j++) {
      // console.log("function name: ", selectorObjects[j].func);
      myFunc = selectorObjects[j].func;

      try {
        res = await myContractInstance.methods[myFunc](...[...Array(finalGettersParams[j].__length__).keys()].map(key => finalGettersParams[j][key])).call({from: account1})  // without input
        console.log("Getter output", res);
        statusArr.push(res)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Getter output: ERROR !", error);
        noOfErrors++;
        statusArr.push(noOfErrors)
      }

    }       

  // return statusArr;
}

async function main() {
  myData =  fs.readFileSync('./param/param0.txt', 'utf8').split('\n');

  for(r=0; r<myData.length; r++) {

    for(let i = 0; i < finalGetters[r].length; i++){
      for(let j =0; j < finalSetters[r].length; j++){
        console.log("============TestCase No. "+r+"  Getter  g"+i+"  Setter   s"+j+"=================")
      var myReceipt = await finalDeploy(r);
      console.log("============  Setter Function of Contract No. ", r);
      var myget = await finalSettersFunctions(myReceipt, r,j);
    console.log("============ NORMAL ORDER Status Functions of Contract No. ", r);
        var myset =await finalGetStatus(prvResult, myReceipt);
      }
    }
  }
}
main().then(() => {
    console.log("ALL has been DONE !")
  })
```

and myData is all my testcases/parameters like this `[c1(constructor), g1, g2, s1, s2, s3, g3, g4, s4, g5, g6.........]`... it should be noted that these values are encoded pareamters like this `[0x000000, 0x123fs000, ........, 0x23abc220000]`and also noted that myData contain millions of such testcase.. 
in finalGetters = [g1, g2, g3,.. ], finalSetter =[s1, s2, s3...]

Ganche GUI version: v2.1.2
Web3 version: web3@1.2.4
Node version: v10.17.0
Windows 10

Comment: How do you interact with Ganache? Truffle 4? Truffle 5? A standalone web3 script? Something else?

Comment: standalone web3 script..

Comment: Please share it, and also indicate what Ganache and Web3 versions you are using.

Comment: Ganace GUI version is : v2.1.2 and web3 : web3@1.2.4

Comment: Why don't you use ganache-cli? And where is your script?

Comment: now i am using ganache-cli... and what do you means "where is your script? " .. my whole program ? my deploy function? my setter/getter function ?

Comment: So what is your ganache-cli version then??? I mean the part which gets you to `Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""`. How are we supposed to help you fix this error when we have no idea what code brings you to it??? Your question is under the assumption that everything is fine on your side, and there's some problem or bug in Ganache. Most chances are that this is in fact the other way around, since Ganache is widely in use and thus thoroughly verified by the community, while your code isn't.

Comment: no no... for cli , my program is running (2 hours elapsed )  , i have not test/received such error till now for cli..

Comment: "for cli , my program is running" - that's not a version! Please run `npm ls ganache` on your machine and report back with the actual version! Also "i have not test/received such error till now" doesn't imply that your code is good and Ganache is bad. I, for instant, have received this error hundreds of times, and I therefore wrap my web3 calls with a function that handles this problem. It is quite a common issue in web3.js, whether you're working with public nodes like Infura, or with private nodes like Ganache.

Comment: i have already said that my Ganache GUI version.. but for cli i didn't experience such error yet, if i found such error for cli then update you.. for now just considered GUI not cli... see my update

Comment: yes, now i have also tried Ganache CLI v6.7.0 (ganache-core: 2.8.0), and the same problem...

Comment: Can you please note at which line of code you get this error?

Comment: actually, it depend on my execution ... sometime, it stop on getter function, some time it stop on setter function... if i am working on my laptop, then it never stop ...but i left my laptop unattended then after some time (i don't know exactly how much time) ganache cli become unresponsive  and gives this error Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
 it means the problem is not in my code... if my code has problem, then it should also be stopped during my working hours...

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap each one of your getter function calls with this:

```
async function rpc(func) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            return await func;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            if (!error.message.startsWith("Invalid JSON RPC response"))
                throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

For example, change this:

```
res = await myContractInstance.methods[myFunc](xxx).call(yyy);
```

To this:

```
res = await rpc(myContractInstance.methods[myFunc](xxx).call(yyy));
```

Comment: @AmirAli: "due to my laptop is in use"??? Doesn't that imply anything to you? You have not disabled all the "sleep" features in your OS! This issue has got nothing to do with your code, so changing the code won't fix it!!! I'll delete this answer in a few minutes.

Comment: i have disabled all sleep option , but could not figure it out why this happened...

Comment: @AmirAli: In any case, that should keep your program pending until you get back to work and start using your PC again (i.e., it will keep retrying the same method as long as the `Invalid JSON RPC response` exception is thrown). If you wanna retain your printouts prior to this error, then remove the `console.log(error.message);` statement (or extend the `rpc` function with a mechanism which ensures that it this error message not printed more than once per function-call).